# The method isn't defined for type ''

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting the following 2 errors from the same block of code after upgrading flutter_slidable to version 2.0: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_slidable

> The named parameter isn't defined.

> The method isn't defined for type 'class name'

Named parameters showing errors:actionPane,actionExtentRatio,secondaryActions,tile

Methods showing errors:SlidableDrawerActionPane,IconSlideAction

Code Snippet 1 :

```
tile = Slidable(
  actionPane: SlidableDrawerActionPane(),
  actionExtentRatio: 0.25,
  child: tile,
  secondaryActions: <Widget>[
    IconSlideAction(
        caption: _localizationService.user__connections_circle_delete,
        color: Colors.red,
        icon: Icons.delete,
        onTap: _deleteConnectionsCircle),
  ],
);
```

Similarly, Code snippet 2:

```html
Widget tile = Slidable(
      actionPane: SlidableDrawerActionPane(),
      actionExtentRatio: 0.25,
      child: ListTile(
          onTap: () {
            navigationService.navigateToFollowsList(
                followsList: widget.followsList, context: context);
          },
          leading: OBEmoji(widget.followsList.emoji!),
          title: OBText(
            widget.followsList.name!,
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          subtitle: OBSecondaryText(
              widget.followsList.followsCount.toString() + ' users')),
      secondaryActions: <Widget>[
        new IconSlideAction(
            caption: 'Delete',
            color: Colors.red,
            icon: Icons.delete,
            onTap: _deleteFollowsList),
      ],
    );
```

Code snippet 2 has been transformed to(Code snippet 1 already has been solved) :

```html
Widget tile = Slidable(
      endActionPane: ActionPane(
          extentRatio: 0.25,
          motion: const DrawerMotion(),
          children: [
            SlidableAction(
              label: 'Delete',
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              icon: Icons.delete,
              onPressed: (context) {
                _deleteFollowsList;
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
                onTap: () {
                  navigationService.navigateToFollowsList(
                      followsList: widget.followsList, context: context);
                },
                leading: OBEmoji(widget.followsList.emoji!),
                title: OBText(
                  widget.followsList.name!,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                subtitle: OBSecondaryText(
                    '${widget.followsList.followsCount} users')),
          ]),
      child: tile,
    );
```

I'm not sure if the above transformation is correct. Also, i'm gettin an error :

> Local variable 'tile' can't be referenced before it is declared.

The above error appeared after quick fix for :

> The named parameter 'child' is required, but there's no corresponding argument.
> Try adding the required argument

I'm testing an open source App :
The same code is available : https://github.com/OkunaOrg/okuna-app/blob/master/lib/pages/home/pages/menu/pages/connections_circles/widgets/connections_circle_tile.dart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the package read me, the package had migration, you need to read this [link](https://github.com/letsar/flutter_slidable/wiki/Migration-from-version-0.6.0-to-version-1.0.0) to apply those changes. like this:

```
Slidable(
        endActionPane: ActionPane(
          motion: const DrawerMotion(),
          extentRatio: 0.25,
          children: [
            SlidableAction(
              label: _localizationService.user__connections_circle_delete,
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              icon: Icons.delete,
              onPressed: (context) {
                _deleteConnectionsCircle();
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
        child: Container(),
      ),
```

Comment: What will  onTap: _deleteConnectionsCircle change to?

Comment: It will change to this: onPressed: (context) {_deleteConnectionsCircle();},

Comment: Hi. Can you help me with the 2nd snippet I've just updated ?. I did the changes but still getting an error.

Comment: you can't pass tile as child of Slidable when you try initialize it.